# Why is this Swift function returning Array index is out of range?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, duplicates

So I'm trying to solve the Remove Duplicates from sorted array problem on Leet code with the function that follows. But when it's tested with [1,1] as input somehow I get Array index is out of range, even though I have some conditional logic at the start that should catch that case without triggering the Array index is out of range. Even more confusing: it works in playgrounds Xcode 11.1, but not with whatever version of Swift Leet code is running.

```
class Solution {
   func removeDuplicates(_ nums: inout [Int]) -> Int {
    var slowPointer = 0
    var fastPointer = 1

    if nums.count < 2 {
        return nums.count
    }

    if nums.count == 2 {
        if nums[slowPointer] == nums[fastPointer] {
            nums.remove(at: 1)
        }
        return 2
    }

    while fastPointer < nums.count {


        while nums[fastPointer] == nums[slowPointer] {
            fastPointer += 1
        }

        if fastPointer < nums.count {
            slowPointer += 1
            nums[slowPointer] = nums[fastPointer]
            fastPointer += 1
        }

        print(slowPointer, fastPointer)
    }

    return (slowPointer + 1)

    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Fatal error: Array index is out of range
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f75269f5050 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 69
1    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f7526902dc6 <unavailable> + 3280326
2    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f7526903145 <unavailable> + 3281221
3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f7526921043 <unavailable> + 3403843
4    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f7526714b10 Array.subscript.getter + 39
5                                       0x00005595496f1a40 <unavailable> + 19008
6                                       0x00005595496f1054 <unavailable> + 16468
7    libc.so.6                          0x00007f7524836740 __libc_start_main + 240
8                                       0x00005595496f0dd9 <unavailable> + 15833
```

Comment: Step through it in the debugger.

Comment: Is the error occurring on the `while nums[fastPointer] == nums[slowPointer]` line?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. No errors...

Comment: @DavidChopin I mean it shouldn't hit that line

Comment: @Alexander except that it runs fine in playgrounds.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for testing. not sure why it doesn't work on leet code. more weird than important

Answer (score 0):

This code looks to be wrong:

```
if nums.count == 2 {
    if nums[slowPointer] == nums[fastPointer] {
        nums.remove(at: 1)
    }
    return 2
}
```

If `nums.count` is 2, and the two entries are the same (your `[1,1]` case, you first remove one of the objects, then return 2. So in that case you return an array containing a single element but a count of 2.

To fix your code, return nums.count, not 2, for that case:

```
if nums.count == 2 {
    if nums[slowPointer] == nums[fastPointer] {
        nums.remove(at: 1)
    }
    nums.count
}
```

### Edit: The comment below is wrong.

Note that even if you fix that bug, your code has O(N^2) performance. That's not good.

Comment: @MartinR, I misread that code. I guess you're right and it has O(n). It takes advantage of the fact that the arrays are ordered.